# How to dispatch a value from Textarea to store React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have question about how to pass textarea value by dispatch and save to store.

My reducer like this:

```
var defaultCommentState = {
    login_status: false,
    author_name: '',
    author_email: '',
    author_url: 'https://google.com',
    content: '',
    post:null,
    parent:0
}
const addComment = (state = defaultCommentState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_COMMENT_CONTENT':
        return {
            ...state, 
            content: action.content
        }
        default:
            return state; 
    }
}

export default addComment;
```

My form like this:

```
<form name="post_comment" className="post-a--comment" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   <div className="thecmstatus" />
   <label>Message (You signed in as <span>{author_name}</span>)</label>
   <textarea id="content" 
             onChange={this.handlecontent}
             value={this.state.content}
             required="required" /> <br/>
   <button type="submit"
            id="blog_post_submit"
            className="btn-default btn">
            Submit
   </button>
</form>
```

My action like this:

```
const addcommentcontent = (content) => {
    return {
        type: 'ADD_COMMENT_CONTENT',
        content
    }
}
```

I can dispatch on state change with `onChange` function but it is good way.

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        this.setState({
            ...this.props.addComment,
            content:this.props.content
        })
        this.props.onSubmit(this.props.addComment);
    }
    handlecontent = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            content: e.target.value
        }) 
        //I dispatch on state change but I think it is not good
        const {commentcontentadded} = this.props;
        commentcontentadded(this.state.content);
    }
```

Can you tell me how to pass textarea value to store by dispatch because I need to submit payload from store instead of state like this.

```
this.props.onSubmit(this.props.addComment)
```

Comment: can you also include the code for `this.props.onSubmit`? I assume its another dispatcher?

Comment: @mxdi9i7 this.props.onSubmit is just call submit from props, not dispatcher

Comment: Anyone has the answer for my question? I really need your help !!

Comment: are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: @mxdi9i7 there is no error. Please take a look on handlecontent. I pass state with dispatch to store by this way but it returns many dispatchs on typing. It is not good

Answer (score -1):

Import Action creator (addcommentcontent), and dispatch him in handleSubmit method.

```js
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    this.setState({
        ...this.props.addComment,
        content:this.props.content
    })
    
    dispatch(addcommentcontent(this.state.content));
}
```

Comment: dispatch on Submit is unable to set content

Comment: When you press submit button you call handleSubmit method. So you need just call dispatch in body method. P.S. What is this this.props.onSubmit?